# What is hardware type ID in keylayout xml file?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

In a ".keylayout" file there is `<layout>` element where you can specify a "mapSet" and "modifierMap" for a range of keyboard types. Apples [Technical Note TN2056](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2056/_index.html) describes the XML file structure, but not what a "keyboard type hardware ID" actually is. They say:

> Apple will map new keyboard hardware IDs to one of the existing ones,
>   so it is usually sufficient to copy and paste the entire 
>   element from an existing keyboard layout.

Great, but I really would like to understand what this ID is.

At first look it seems like ID 0 through 17 are ANSI keyboards, but when I look at the key layout for European layouts (which are usually ISO keyboards) I find ID 0 and 1, so I guess the IDs are not related to ANSI/ISO/JIS.

Answer (score 1):

I got an excellent answer in the Google Group "Ukelele Users" ([link directly to the answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ukelele-users/Zg6owIiVWVc/iVG-MwcVEAAJ)) from John Brownie. The hardware ID is what is returned by `CGEventSourceGetKeyboardType`. Mr Brownie writes:

> The keyboard ID is what is reported back to the system when certain
>   system calls are made. Historically, these were 'gestalt' calls, but
>   currently it uses Quartz Events, calling CGEventSourceGetKeyboardType.

**For a list of IDs, see the [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ukelele-users/Zg6owIiVWVc/iVG-MwcVEAAJ) in the group.**